# Installing IntelliJ IDEA on Lubuntu

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, intellij

I try to install IntelliJ IDEA on **L**ubuntu. I've downloaded and unpacked the archive. But when i run idea.ch i get this error:

```
Start Failed: Failed to initialize graphics environment
java.awt.AWTError: Assistive Technology not found:    org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper
at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.newAWTError(Toolkit.java:472)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.fallbackToLoadClassForAT(Toolkit.java:488)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
at java.base/java.util.HashMap$KeySpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1608)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.loadAssistiveTechnologies(Toolkit.java:532)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:613)
at com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.updateFrameClass(AppUIUtil.java:155)
at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareAndStart(StartupUtil.java:94)
at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:20)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.lambda$start$0(PluginManager.java:75)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:374)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.fallbackToLoadClassForAT(Toolkit.java:485)
... 20 more
```

It seems like **L**ubuntu is lacking some required component. What should I do?